# Why the humidity in DLNM(R) showed coef/vcov not consistent with basis matrix, but temperature was OK

Tags: r, gl-matrix

everyone. I am using DLNM in R to analyze to lag-effect of climatic conditions on the prevalence of the disease.
I followed somebody else's program strictly
, and it worked in avg.temp and max.speed, but showed err "**coef/vcov not consistent with basis matrix**" in avg.ap and avg.hum. However, i just changed the variables set in code, and never changed other code.
I have a hypothesis that maybe DLNM doesn't like wet weather. **T T**
I don't know what to do, can you help me?

Part 1 was the Successfully run code, part 2 was the code that showed err, and part 3 was the data I used.
Thank you very much. I hope you can help me

**Part 1. Successfully run code**

```
attach(cpdlnm)
cb.temp = crossbasis(avg.temp, lag=1 ,
                 argvar=list(fun="ns", 
                            knots= c(10)),
                arglag=list(fun="lin"))

modeltemp = glm(pre1 ~ cb.temp +
           ns(no,1*1), 
           family=quasipoisson(), cpdlnm) 

pred1.temp = crosspred(cb.temp, 
                  modelhum,
                  cen=round(median(avg.temp)),
                  bylag=1)
```

**Part 2. Error code**

```
attach(cpdlnm)
cb.hum = crossbasis(avg.hum, lag=1 ,
                 argvar=list(fun="ns", 
                            knots= c(10)),
                arglag=list(fun="lin"))

modelhum = glm(pre1 ~ cb.hum +
           ns(no,1*1), 
           family=quasipoisson(), cpdlnm) 

pred1.hum = crosspred(cb.hum, # This step shows "coef/vcov not consistent with basis matrix"
                  modelhum,
                  cen=round(median(avg.hum)),
                  bylag=0.1)
```

**Part 3. the data are as following:**

```
no  pre1    date    year    month   avg.ap  avg.temp    avg.hum max.speed
1   3.23    12-Jan  2012    1   996.60  9.00    81.60   5.30 
2   6.04    12-Feb  2012    2   993.20  10.90   80.80   6.20 
3   5.18    12-Mar  2012    3   991.00  16.40   78.70   7.60 
4   4.07    12-Apr  2012    4   985.40  23.50   73.50   7.40 
5   4.88    12-May  2012    5   982.60  26.30   77.20   7.00 
6   5.11    12-Jun  2012    6   978.10  27.00   81.30   6.20 
7   6.18    12-Jul  2012    7   979.50  28.10   77.70   6.40 
8   6.17    12-Aug  2012    8   980.40  28.00   75.60   7.90 
9   5.18    12-Sep  2012    9   987.60  25.30   73.60   6.30
```

10   5.16    12-Oct  2012    10  990.70  23.60   72.20   6.20
11   4.61    12-Nov  2012    11  991.70  18.00   79.70   6.90
12   5.26    12-Dec  2012    12  995.00  13.20   74.90   6.50
13   3.79    13-Jan  2013    1   997.10  11.20   78.40   5.70
14   3.87    13-Feb  2013    2   993.50  15.30   82.20   6.50
15   3.37    13-Mar  2013    3   989.90  20.20   74.20   8.00
16   2.85    13-Apr  2013    4   987.00  21.50   78.50   7.70
17   4.38    13-May  2013    5   983.30  25.60   79.20   6.80
18   5.67    13-Jun  2013    6   980.60  27.40   76.90   6.60
19   6.45    13-Jul  2013    7   981.30  28.00   77.50   7.10
20   6.95    13-Aug  2013    8   980.50  27.90   78.20   7.90
21   6.51    13-Sep  2013    9   985.90  25.40   77.60   6.00
22   8.16    13-Oct  2013    10  992.20  22.10   68.80   5.30
23   5.34    13-Nov  2013    11  994.50  18.70   72.30   6.20
24   6.18    13-Dec  2013    12  997.30  11.70   67.20   5.30
25   5.69    14-Jan  2014    1   996.70  12.70   70.30   6.00
26   6.44    14-Feb  2014    2   993.00  12.10   76.90   6.40
27   4.16    14-Mar  2014    3   991.60  16.50   83.90   7.30
28   4.13    14-Apr  2014    4   987.60  22.60   82.40   6.70
29   3.96    14-May  2014    5   983.60  25.70   78.80   7.70
30   4.72    14-Jun  2014    6   979.20  27.70   81.40   7.90
31   5.21    14-Jul  2014    7   980.70  28.30   80.20   9.40
32   5.29    14-Aug  2014    8   982.40  27.50   81.30   7.50
33   6.74    14-Sep  2014    9   984.70  27.10   77.70   8.50
34   4.80    14-Oct  2014    10  991.20  23.90   73.10   5.90
35   4.31    14-Nov  2014    11  993.30  18.60   79.60   6.20
36   4.35    14-Dec  2014    12  998.70  12.30   67.30   5.90
37   2.95    15-Jan  2015    1   996.70  13.30   76.30   6.20
38   4.63    15-Feb  2015    2   993.50  15.50   78.30   6.50
39   4.00    15-Mar  2015    3   991.70  17.70   83.40   6.30
40   4.16    15-Apr  2015    4   988.40  22.80   70.20   7.30
41   4.67    15-May  2015    5   982.40  26.70   80.50   8.00
42   5.62    15-Jun  2015    6   980.90  28.20   81.00   7.40
43   5.04    15-Jul  2015    7   980.20  27.30   79.40   6.70
44   5.79    15-Aug  2015    8   982.40  27.60   80.10   6.50
45   5.28    15-Sep  2015    9   986.30  26.00   84.60   6.50
46   4.39    15-Oct  2015    10  991.20  23.00   78.30   6.90
47   4.13    15-Nov  2015    11  993.50  19.40   85.30   6.90
48   3.30    15-Dec  2015    12  997.80  13.00   80.90   5.70
49   5.30    16-Jan  2016    1   996.00  11.80   82.30   6.40
50   4.57    16-Feb  2016    2   997.80  12.20   68.90   7.00
51   4.66    16-Mar  2016    3   991.70  17.00   78.90   7.00
52   4.01    16-Apr  2016    4   984.60  23.40   80.90   9.80
53   4.90    16-May  2016    5   983.80  25.50   78.70   8.30
54   3.75    16-Jun  2016    6   981.70  28.20   78.80   7.70
55   3.13    16-Jul  2016    7   981.10  28.90   77.60   7.60
56   3.25    16-Aug  2016    8   979.00  28.00   79.80   8.70
57   2.93    16-Sep  2016    9   984.30  26.60   75.20   6.40
58   2.93    16-Oct  2016    10  987.90  24.40   72.90   7.00
59   3.08    16-Nov  2016    11  993.40  18.10   79.60   6.70
60   2.99    16-Dec  2016    12  995.70  15.40   71.70   6.80
61   3.10    17-Jan  2017    1   994.70  14.50   79.20   6.50
62   3.75    17-Feb  2017    2   994.80  14.70   71.50   8.30
63   3.49    17-Mar  2017    3   990.20  16.50   83.60   8.50
64   3.36    17-Apr  2017    4   986.80  21.90   76.70   7.80
65   3.69    17-May  2017    5   985.00  24.80   77.50   10.00
66   3.76    17-Jun  2017    6   980.20  26.90   84.80   8.50
67   2.69    17-Jul  2017    7   981.00  27.50   83.60   9.80
68   3.05    17-Aug  2017    8   980.50  27.70   83.40   9.00
69   3.05    17-Sep  2017    9   984.20  27.60   81.50   7.10
70   2.46    17-Oct  2017    10  990.00  22.80   75.90   7.90
71   2.08    17-Nov  2017    11  993.00  17.80   79.50   7.00
72   2.32    17-Dec  2017    12  996.90  13.30   69.30   6.90
73   2.53    18-Jan  2018    1   992.10  12.00   78.40   8.10
74   3.29    18-Feb  2018    2   992.90  13.40   68.70   7.20
75   3.03    18-Mar  2018    3   988.30  19.20   78.20   9.10
76   2.30    18-Apr  2018    4   986.50  21.80   77.30   8.70
77   1.75    18-May  2018    5   982.60  26.70   79.40   8.90
78   2.03    18-Jun  2018    6   978.30  26.90   81.60   9.00
79   2.79    18-Jul  2018    7   976.80  27.90   82.10   9.20
80   2.32    18-Aug  2018    8   976.40  27.50   83.40   9.60
81   1.88    18-Sep  2018    9   983.50  26.10   80.10   8.90
82   2.76    18-Oct  2018    10  990.50  21.10   78.70   7.10
83   2.14    18-Nov  2018    11  991.50  18.20   80.30   7.10
84   1.78    18-Dec  2018    12  994.50  13.00   84.00   7.80
85   2.77    19-Jan  2019    1   995.20  11.70   84.50   7.30
86   4.60    19-Feb  2019    2   990.50  13.70   84.80   8.10
87   2.32    19-Mar  2019    3   987.70  17.30   85.90   9.90
88   2.07    19-Apr  2019    4   983.60  23.10   84.80   9.80
89   2.97    19-May  2019    5   981.80  24.30   83.20   7.70
90   2.48    19-Jun  2019    6   977.80  27.50   84.80   9.00
91   2.32    19-Jul  2019    7   977.20  27.80   85.00   8.90
92   2.06    19-Aug  2019    8   977.20  28.30   81.20   10.30
93   2.10    19-Sep  2019    9   984.60  26.40   72.70   8.20
94   2.89    19-Oct  2019    10  989.10  22.70   78.00   7.00

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that when you specify "knots= c(10)", 10 is within the range of temperature but not the same for humidity (if the min>10, then the lag can't be defined).